# Using LibraryImport to import same function in multiple dlls

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke, dllimport

I am creating a .net WebAPI to facilitate a gradual move from Delphi code to C#, but our codebase is very large at 1.5M+ lines of code. So we are trying to break our application into small libraries we can load into the C# API and then gradually rewrite the functions or services over time. We have decided that our libraries will export 3 common functions:
`Initialize`, `Execute`, `DisposeStr`. All dlls we create will export these functions so that we have a common way to communicate with our native code.

My issue is that I will have a `DelphiEmployeeService.cs`, `DelphiWorktimeService.cs` etc. (Maybe a hundred times over) and I would need to have basically the same lines in the beginning of each service wrapper:

```cs
[LibraryImport("<DLLNAME>", EntryPoint = "Initialize")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[UnmanagedCallConv(CallConvs = new Type[] { typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvStdcall) })]
private static partial bool Initialize();

[LibraryImport("<DLLNAME>", EntryPoint = "Execute", StringMarshalling = StringMarshalling.Utf16)]
[UnmanagedCallConv(CallConvs = new Type[] { typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvStdcall) })]
private static partial IntPtr Execute(string parameters);

[LibraryImport("<DLLNAME>", EntryPoint = "DisposeStr")]
[UnmanagedCallConv(CallConvs = new Type[] { typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvStdcall) })]
private static partial void DisposeStr(IntPtr str);
```

To get around this I wanted to make a `DelphiImplementation.cs` base class, but I am unsure on how to make the descendants register which dll name to load...

What I would like would be something along the lines of

```cs
public class DelphiImplementation
{
  protected abstract string LibraryName;

  [LibraryImport(LibraryName, EntryPoint = "Initialize")]
  [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
  [UnmanagedCallConv(CallConvs = new Type[] {typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvStdcall) })]
  private static partial bool Initialize();

  [LibraryImport(LibraryName, EntryPoint = "Execute", StringMarshalling = StringMarshalling.Utf16)]
  [UnmanagedCallConv(CallConvs = new Type[] { typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvStdcall) })]
  private static partial IntPtr Execute(string parameters);

  [LibraryImport(LibraryName, EntryPoint = "DisposeStr")]
  [UnmanagedCallConv(CallConvs = new Type[] { typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvStdcall) })]
  private static partial void DisposeStr(IntPtr str);
}
public class EmployeeDelphiService : DelphiImplementation
{
  protected override string LibraryName => "Employee.dll"
}
```

Is something like this even possible?

Comment: If you want to load dlls dynamically you might want to take a look at [UnmanagedLibrary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jmstall/type-safe-managed-wrappers-for-kernel32getprocaddress). Note that I have not used it. Otherwise you might need to look at some form of code generation. Attributes are compile time things, so cannot use runtime things, like the type of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`NativeLibrary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.nativelibrary?view=net-7.0) class to dynamically load DLLs and execute the functions. It should be fairly simple to create delegates from the function pointers, and store them in the class in order to call them.

```cs
public class DelphiImplementation
{
    protected abstract string LibraryName { get; }

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    protected delegate bool InitializeDelegate();

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    protected delegate IntPtr ExecuteDelegate(string parameters);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    protected delegate void DisposeStrDelegate(IntPtr str);

    private IntPtr Handle { get; } = NativeLibrary.Load(LibraryName);

    protected InitializeDelegate Initialize { get; }

    protected ExecuteDelegate Execute { get; }

    protected InitializeDelegate DisposeStr { get; }

    protected DelphiImplementation()
    {
        Initialize = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<InitializeDelegate>(NativeLibrary.GetExport(Handle, nameof(Initialize)));        
        Execute = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<ExecuteDelegate>(NativeLibrary.GetExport(Handle, nameof(Execute)));
        DisposeStr = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<DisposeStrDelegate>(NativeLibrary.GetExport(Handle, nameof(DisposeStr)));
    }
}
```

You can the simply do `someImplementation.Initialize()` etc.

If you want to unload the DLL after use then you can use `IDisposable` with a `using`.

```cs
public class DelphiImplementation : IDisposable
{
....

    public void Dispose()
    {
        NativeLibrary.Free(Handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thanks a bunch. Do I need to unload the or de-allocate the Handle again after use?

Comment: Only if you want to unload the DLL. If you plan on continually using it in your app then there is no point. If you do want to then make this class `IDisposable`, which has `Dispose() => NativeLibrary.Free(Handle);`